# Laravel relation query returns the related ID instead of the main

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables `Models` and `Cars` related as per `cars.model_id = model.id`.
*Car* `belongsTo` *Model* and *Model* `hasMany` *Cars*.

When I would like to do a search based on the `Model` name in the `cars` table I do the following query:

```
Car::join('models', 'cars.model_id', '=', 'models.id)
   ->where('models.name', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')
   ->paginate($_ENV['ITEMS_PER_PAGE']);
```

My problem is that Eloquent ORM of Laravel in that case returns the model.id as the main id, so resultset will have the model.id as Id instead of the Car.id. Any solution for that?

As per the documentation of Laravel, I thought that Eloquent would assume correctly the table Id without any help:

> Note: Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key
>   column named id. You may define a primaryKey property to override this
>   convention. Likewise, you may define a connection property to override
>   the name of the database connection that should be used when utilizing
>   the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't `SELECT` `id` or none of the models fields if you don't need them (`where` clause will work anyway)

```
Car::join('models', 'cars.model_id', '=', 'models.id')
 ->where('models.name', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')
 ->paginate($_ENV['ITEMS_PER_PAGE'], ['cars.*','models.fieldsYouNeedOrNothing']);
```

---

side note: You can use `whereHas()` instead of join to do it more 'eloquent' way if you really don't need joined table's fields:

```
Car::whereHas('models', function ($query) use ($term) {
   $query->where('models.name', 'like', '%'.$term.'%');
})->paginate($_ENV['ITEMS_PER_PAGE']);
```

This will run subquery on models table and leave you without any worries about the keys.

Comment: Brilliant, however doesn't answer my question which is: why this happens if the docs says that Eloquent would assume correctly the Id.

Comment: You know, this note doesn't belong to joins and does not apply here. Answer to your question is pretty obvious - you get `id` from one table and `id` from another - how would you distinguish them without aliasing? If you want the other key you need to alias it assuming both fields are named `id`

Comment: First: Your solution doesn't work, I cannot select columns inside the paginate method. (At least in 4.1 it gives syntax error)
Second: I am just referring to the documentation of Laravel, how he does that I don't care, that is why I am using it. I would select explicitly by table name like models.id, and cars.id, it should be enough to differentiate, but as the docs says and I have repeated 3 times already, Eloquent should be able to do that for me, but it does not work.

Comment: I'm not gonna argue about that. paginate takes columns as 2nd param, so show the error it throws. And are you seeking for help to solve the problem or going to blame the tool you are using? This note says nothing more but that Eloquent assumes every table's primary key is named `id`.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, so from your part that should end  the discussion, because as you said it solves my problem. Agreed and thanks for that. And agreed that it doesn't help to argue about it.